# get a value from option with beatifulsoup

Tags: findall

I want to get the value "Abelay" from this htmltext:

```
</option>
<option
data-quantity="49"
data-quantity="49"
data-customer-type="family_with_children"
data-score=""
data-dist="2"
data-pagename="abelay"
```

but this code show tons of options that I dont need. I know it is because I code "find_all".

Do you know how to reduce the results for getting only the data-pagename="abelay" result. I need to store this value.

I will really appreciate your help.  I am not skilled in Python by the moment.

Salut!!